# Updating label inside of function in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

So i have problem with updating labels(i want to change colors of text) inside of function in tkinter. It works correctly when I use variable to store label however when i use list to do that, It doesnt. This how define labels.

```
for i in range(9):
    for a in range(9):
        if (NumbersSudoku[a][i] != 0):
            label_frame = Frame(root, width=35, height=35, bg="white")
            label_frame.grid_propagate(False)
            label_frame.grid(row=i, column=a)
            label[i][a] = Label(label_frame, text=NumbersSudoku[a][i], fg="blue", borderwidth=2, width=4, height=2,
                                relief="groove")
            label[i][a].grid(row=i, column=a)
        else:
            label_frame = Frame(root, width=35, height=35, bg="white")
            label_frame.grid_propagate(False)
            label_frame.grid(row=i, column=a)
            label[i][a] = Label(label_frame, borderwidth=2, textvariable=v[i][a], relief="groove", width=4, height=2,
                                fg='brown')
            label[i][a].grid(row=i, column=a)
            print(type(label[i][a]))
gnabel = Label(root, borderwidth=2, text='', relief="groove", width=4, height=2,
               fg='brown')
gnabel.grid(row=14, column=14)
```

This is how i define list.

```
label = []
for x in range(9):
    label.append([])
    for y in range(9):
        label[x].append([])
```

Inside a function printing types of variable and list returns diffrent results even tho when checked outside of function it returns the same <class 'tkinter.Label'>.

```
def base_info():
    global gnabel
    global label
    print(type(gnabel))  # <class 'tkinter.Label'>
    print(type(label))  # <class 'NoneType'>
............

# label[y][x] = Label(root, text=NumbersSudoku[y][x], fg="green").grid(row=y,column=x) # doesnt work
                # gnabel = Label(root, text=NumbersSudoku[y][x], fg="orange").grid(row=14, column=14) # work
```

Comment: Please combine the code into a single [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I can't really give you an answer in relation to your example, but I can give you an example using the function .config()

```
label = Label(root, fg = "green")
label.pack()

def update_label():
    label.config(fg = "red")

update_label()
```

An explanation of what I've done is I've created the label with a foreground of green, and called a function which is going to change that to red. You can do this with text, with size, etc, as long as you use the config() function.

If you don't really understand what I'm saying, there are many youtube videos you can find which will give a better explanation of the config() function.